Inside PnP Modern Search Web part, add 2 hours to {{ getDate (getDate (slot item @root.slots.PUETA) "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.0000000
I have this formula inside PnP Modern Search web part:-
{{ getDate (getDate (slot item @root.slots.PUETA) "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.0000000\Z") "MMMM DD, YYYY h:mm a" 3 }} 

to format a date time, and allow it to follow the time zone of the site.. my question is how i can add 2 hours to the generated date/time from the above formula?
Thanks
